# Why do I see different behavior on this Spring repository when it is imported as a dependency into another project?

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate, maven, jpa

I am seeing different behavior from a Spring annotated repository when I run my project independently vs. when I add the project as a maven dependency. The `delete` method on [the Spring CrudRepository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html) seems to be where I am seeing the strange behavior.

Here are what I believe are the pertinent pieces of my interface and related entities:

```
@Repository
public interface JpaProfileRepo extends ProfileRepo, JpaRepository<UserProfileEntity, Long>, GsonProvider {

    @Transactional
    default void removeProfile(Profile profile){
        if(profile == null){
            throw new MissingKeyDataException("Missing valid ProfileModel object during removeProfile");
        }
        UserProfileEntity entity = findEntityByKeys(profile);
        if (entity == null) throw new DoesNotExistException();

        try{
            this.delete(entity);
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            throw new DoesNotExistException();
        }
    }
}
```

```
public interface ProfileRepo {
    void removeProfile(Profile profile);
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="user_profiles")
public class UserProfileEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "user_profiles_id_seq", sequenceName = "user_profiles_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "user_profiles_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private UserEntity user;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "permissions", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String permissions;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users", uniqueConstraints ={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"email_address"})
})
public class UserEntity {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "users_id_seq", sequenceName = "users_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "users_id_seq")
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "email_address", updatable = false)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "preferences", columnDefinition="TEXT")
    private String preferences;
```

When I debug through the `removeProfile` method on the original project, I run a query on the `user_profiles` table before and after I execute `this.delete(entity)`. I can confirm the table entry for the entity passed into the `removeProfile` method is present before that line runs and deleted after that line runs.

When I debug the same code when it is being called from the parent project, I run the same query for the presence of the table entry for the entity passed into the `removeProfile` method before and after. In this case the table entry is not deleted, but I don't see any exception thrown or any other error - the row just doesn't get deleted as I would expect.

One additional wrinkle I want to mention is that I am using IntelliJ and have my local database connection configured in both projects. When I run `select * from pg_catalog.pg_tables;` from a postgres console in the original project, I see the `user_profiles` and `users` tables come back in the list of tables on the database. When I run the same query on the parent project, I don't see the `user_profiles` and `users` tables in the list of tables on the database, I only see the default postgres tables. Is it possible I have some sort of error based on connecting to the same local database from two separate projects? If that was the case I would expect the parent project to actually fail to connect to the database, rather than show a successful connection but quietly fail to run a database query.

For reference here is everything database related from the two project properties files:

Original project:

```
spring.jpa.database=default

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

datasource.platform=postgres
datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database
sql-dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
datasource.hbm2ddl.auto=

datasource.username=user
datasource.password=
```

Parent project:

```
spring.jpa.database=default

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.show-sql=true

datasource.platform=postgres
datasource.jdbc-url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/database
sql-dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
datasource.hbm2ddl.auto=

datasource.username=user
datasource.password=
```

Seems possible to me the issue could be Spring related, JPA/Hibernate related, Maven related, Postgres related, IntelliJ related, or some delightful combo.  Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

For reference, here are the versions I'm using:
  Spring: 2.0.3
  Postgres: 9.4-1206-jdbc42
  Maven: 2.7
  And here are our hibernate/JPA dependencies:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

And here is the db configuration class I have:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager",
        transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager",
        basePackages = {"com.repositories"}
)
public class DbConfig {
    @Value("${datasource.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String ddlAuto;
    @Value("${sql-dialect}")
    private String dialect;


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactoryBuilder entityManagerFactoryBuilder() {
        return new EntityManagerFactoryBuilder(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter(), new HashMap<>(), null);
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager(
            EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
            @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource)
    {
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",dialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",ddlAuto);

        return builder
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .persistenceUnit("object")
                .properties(properties)
                .packages("com.entities")
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
            @Qualifier("entityManager") EntityManagerFactory
                    entityManagerFactory
    ) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }

}
```

Comment: This might be a long shot but: could you try to `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackges / classes)` and give a direct package to scan the repository? I remember it works with `String` or `Class`. It might be possible that because you import it from a different project, the JPA repository scanning does not work correctly. Might need an `@EntityScan` as well, if entities aren't in the parent project. Note: these should be in the parent project (the one you are actually running)

Comment: @maydawn I've added the configuration class from my parent project to the question - does this cover what you're thinking of?  Anything that looks strange here?

Comment: I don't think so, it seems rather okay to me, but I'm not an expert. I just previously had issues when I used a Spring autoconfiguration project that has similar configuration, in a Spring application. (So I assume our setups were the same). My issue was that the Spring application did not scan the JpaRepository or Entities declared in the autoconfiguration project, so I thought maybe you have the same issue.